# Can I put SQLite database in a folder before root folder of server and give the folder full time read and write access permission?

Tags: php, apache, sqlite

In an Apache linux server,
Can I put SQLite database in a folder before root folder(public-html folder where index.php file could be placed in) of server and give the database folder full time read and write access permission(600)?

Comment: Yes, you can. Just make sure you have write access from PHP to that folder. Usually you can can access the folders that are one level up from the public-html folder. For instance 'tmp'.

Comment: OK, How can I give access to the PHP file then?

Comment: As I explained: You probably don't need to. However, if you want to change access permission you can do that with: [chmod()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php). But you need permission to use it on a folder.

Comment: So there is no security issue there and the mentioned folder will be private just for the PHP code

Comment: Assuming you have such a folder, yes. Anything outside the public-html folder is not accessible from the web. Best thing to do, is to try it. It doesn't have to be a SQLite database, you could try it with a [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) oneliner.

Comment: Amazing! I checked and while the folder's access is 600, yet it is writable by file_put_contents(), FYI I use Core FTP LE software and then set the folder and a file there with 600(write-read just by user) but the file is still writable when I use file_put_contents() in a PHP code in public-html folder

Comment: A permission mode of 600 means read and write access for the owner. Clearly PHP (read: Apache) is a owner of that folder, and probably your Core FTP LE client has access too.

Comment: About owner, how can I see who is the owner?Where can I change the ownership of the PHP file? and About Core FTP LE I use Core FTP LE to change the permission and when I go to properties of the file and folder it shows that the permissions have changed as I changed them

Comment: Ownership of files is a Linux issue. See: [ls](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/ls.htm) and [chown](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/chown.htm), but this should not be discussed here, there's no relation to your question.

Comment: Ok, about the main subject it seems the outside world utilizing a URL can access a folder which is not in public-html folder and is accessed as 600, so how the outside world is the owner of a folder or file with 600 where 600 means no access for outside world?

Comment: You're not making sense. In Linux there are only users. Read [more about permissions](https://www.linux.com/learn/understanding-linux-file-permissions). 1. Apache (= PHP) **is** a user with file permissions. 2. Apache **can only** serve files to which it has access. 3. Apache **will only** serve files located in 'public-html'.

Comment: Ok, thanks, as far as I get, there is yet no problem that the PHP file in public-html can access the file outside public-html because it is still owner but the point I don't understand is how I use file_put_contents() then to check the file outside of public-html is accessible or not (as you suggested) ? In other word how can I check if world has access to my file which is outside of public-html?

Comment: You can test write permission with [file_put_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) by checking what it returns: `echo (file_put_contents(<path>) === false) ? 'not writable' : 'writable';`. Similary you can check read permission with [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php). Secondly, Apache is configured in such a way that it only serves files, to the WWW on port 80 or 443, in the public-html folder or its child folders. This is independent of Linux permissions.

Comment: Where must I use file_put_contents, file_get_contents() cause when I use it in a php code inside public-html and execute that PHP code URL through firefox, it should return writable and readable and it returns  writable and readable cause permission is 600 but the point is how the world permission could be checked, in other word how can I  check the second zero in 600 which is related to the world? I mean I don't want to check 6 in 600

Comment: Ah, I see. Well you can't check the public permission of a file, with 600, owned by Apache, like that, with the user called Apache (= PHP). You would need to check a file, with 600, owen by another user. Permissions are given to three types of entities: users, groups, and public. So a file with 600 could be owned by Apache, but also by another user, and still have the permissions set to 600. I probably make this sound far more complicated than it is....